# In Woocommerce, how do I edit the product url that the shop item links to?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I am trying to set up Woocommerce so that the product information for each item is embedded within another custom Wordpress page, and these replace my product pages for the purposes of shopping.

So when the user clicks on a product in the 'Related Products' section, or in the shop, or in the sidebar, I want them to be taken to the page I have created, *not* the product page generated by Woocommerce.

So instead of linking to booklab/products/product-name/, I want all the shop links to link to booklab/books/product-name/

I have achieved this result in the sidebar widget by copying across the content-widget-product.php template file into my theme and changing the following line:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
```

to this:

```
<a href="/booklab/books/<?php echo $product->post->post_name; ?>/" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
```

However, I can't find the right template file to edit in order to affect the 'Related products' window or the links from the shop. It seems to me it should involve changing this line in the content-single-product.php template file:

```
<meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
```

But as far as I can tell, changing this doesn't affect anything. I can't find anywhere else in the template files where the permalink is referred to, and which I can therefore edit.

Answer (score 0):

'Related products' are located in a woocommerce templates, in the '/single-product/related.php' file, but I'd recommend instead of 'hacking'/'hard-coding' just change settings in the Woocommerce --> Settings --> Products --> Display section simply putting your custom page in place of default 'shop' page (or even simpler you can change the slug of the default 'shop' page).

Also if you need you can set up Custom URL structure in the Settings --> Permalinks --> Product Permalinks section for your shop page.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi bhelmet - many thanks for your input!

Unfortunately, none of these methods produce the result I'm after. Using a custom page for my 'shop' page doesn't affect the individual product pages, or which pages are targeted by links in the 'Related' section.

Changing the Permalinks only changes the URL structure. My problem is that I want to use my own custom pages, with the product information embedded within them, in place of the automatically generated product pages.

Comment: And the 'single-product/related.php' file does not contain any links that I can edit - it embeds template parts from elsewhere and I can't seem to track down where it gets the code for the link.

Comment: Well, then you can create custom loop in reated.php file to fit your specific needs (it uses `content-product.php` file in the loop by default).

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid a custom loop may be a little beyond my ability, and try as I might, I can't find what I should be editing in the content-product.php file.

Comment: I've got a little further with this now. The link I need to change, or overwrite, is in wc-template-functions.php in the 'includes' folder:

`function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
 echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';
}`

Since this isn't in woocommerce's templates folder, I can't edit it directly - I suppose I need to put in my own custom code somewhere to replace it. But since you can't 'echo' within 'echo', I also don't know what I would change this to - I don't want it to grab the permalink but a different page.

Comment: ...it's a bit difficult from my end to represent your situation, and I don't know why your changes does not apply only for related products...anyway take use of `post_type_link` filter to change product urls:

`function customize_product_url( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample ) {
 if( is_product() ) {
  if( 'product' === $post->post_type ) {
   return site_url() . '/' . YOUR_CUSTOM_URL_WITHOUT_HARDCODING;
  }
 }
 return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'customize_product_url', 10, 4 );`

Not very woocommerce-friendly solution, but at least you can achieve your goal.